# Sequential Group By in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, gaps-and-islands

For this Table:

```
+----+--------+-------+
| ID | Status | Value |
+----+--------+-------+
|  1 |      1 |     4 |
|  2 |      1 |     7 |
|  3 |      1 |     9 |
|  4 |      2 |     1 |
|  5 |      2 |     7 |
|  6 |      1 |     8 |
|  7 |      1 |     9 |
|  8 |      2 |     1 |
|  9 |      0 |     4 |
| 10 |      0 |     3 |
| 11 |      0 |     8 |
| 12 |      1 |     9 |
| 13 |      3 |     1 |
+----+--------+-------+
```

I need to sum sequential groups with the same `Status` to produce this result.

```
+--------+------------+
| Status | Sum(Value) |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |         20 |
|      2 |          8 |
|      1 |         17 |
|      2 |          1 |
|      0 |         15 |
|      1 |          9 |
|      3 |          1 |
+--------+------------+
```

How can I do that in SQL Server?

NB: The values in the `ID` column are contiguous.

Comment: Are the `ID` values guaranteed to be contiguous or not? If they are not guaranteed contiguous then what would happen if the row with `ID=2` was missing? Would the rows with Ids `1` and `3` still be regarded as being in the same group? Also please remove the images and provide the example data in text form. This is more accessible as well as making it easier for potential answerers to setup test tables without having to type it out themselves. Look at other questions tagged SQL Server for examples.

Comment: yes, the ID values are guaranteed to be contiguous.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per the tag I added to your question this is a gaps and islands problem.

The best performing solution will likely be

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ID - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [STATUS] ORDER BY [ID]) AS Grp
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT [STATUS],
       SUM([VALUE]) AS [SUM(VALUE)]
FROM   T
GROUP  BY [STATUS],
          Grp
ORDER  BY MIN(ID)
```

If the `ID` values were not guaranteed contiguous as stated then you would need to use

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [ID]) - 
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [STATUS] ORDER BY [ID]) AS Grp
```

Instead in the CTE definition.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a75f/1)

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this works? It's not clear, especially for inexperienced people.

Comment: @arturo on mobile at the moment. See the chapter 5 download at http://www.manning.com/nielsen/SampleChapter5.pdf