# SQL Server Row Partition on the basis of Data Combination

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have data as below:

```
Create table #PP
(
MM int,
PP Int,
DT date
)

insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-01-01')
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-02-01')
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-03-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-04-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,2,'2016-05-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,2,'2016-06-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,2,'2016-07-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,2,'2016-08-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-09-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-10-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-11-01') 
insert into #PP values(1,1,'2016-12-01') 

 select * from #PP
```

[My Data and What I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HMdq.jpg)

```
MM  PP  DT  Sr NO
1   1   01/01/2016  1
1   1   01/02/2016  2    
1   1   01/03/2016  3
1   1   01/04/2016  4
1   2   01/05/2016  1
1   2   01/06/2016  2
1   2   01/07/2016  3
1   2   01/08/2016  4
1   1   01/09/2016  1
1   1   01/10/2016  2
1   1   01/11/2016  3
1   1   01/12/2016  4
```

I have written the Query, but its not working properly

```
 SELECT MM, PP, DT
 , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                    PARTITION BY MM, PP
                    ORDER BY MM, PP
                    )  SRNO
 FROM #PP ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

My Query result is as below, which is wrong
[This is my Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfUsI.jpg)

Comment: This looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459274/sequential-group-by-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

This question is very subtle.  It is important to note that the values are repeated in the `MM` and `PP` columns, but the row numbers should start again.  This is easy enough to fix, using the difference of row numbers:

```
select mm, pp, dt,
       row_number() over (partition by mm, pp, seqnum - seqnum_mp order by dt) as srno
from (select p.*,
             row_number() over (partition by mm, pp order by dt) as seqnum_mp,
             row_number() over (order by dt) as seqnum
      from #pp p
     ) p;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62c02d/1) is a SQL Fiddle showing that it works.

Comment: Hi Gordon... Please  look into  above Query, when I am adding more data with another mm,  Query result is not appropriate as I am looking for

Answer (score 0):

I have  written, this is working for me

```
select mm, pp, dt,
      row_number() over (partition by mm, pp, seqnum - seqnum_mp order by dt) as srno
from (select p.*,
         row_number() over (partition by mm, pp order by dt) as seqnum_mp,
         row_number() over (order by mm,dt) as seqnum
  from #pp p
 ) p;
```